# How can I subtract a number from a value in a C# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to subtract 1 from the value of a `Dictionary<string, int>` as the int contains the numbers of a lot that need to be decreased when a foreach is entered, but I don't seem to find a solution.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> i in myDictionary)

i.Value -= 1;
```

The above is not possible, if I try to do `myDictionary[i] -= 1` I still get errors. Any suggestion?

Comment: That is because the dictionary contains a data type which cannot accept the arithmetic `-` operator aka a string, that would be possible if it were holding only an integer

Comment: How can I change the value of the specific key then?

Comment: `foreach (var key in myDictionary.Keys) myDictionary[key] += 1;`

Comment: Check the comment by DavidG, that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a value of keyvaluepair since it read only. Try this code. it was tested in visual studio

1. you can replace with new keyvaluepairs

```
dict = dict.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value -1);
```

2. or just change value

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myDictionary.Count; i++)
 {
        string key = dict.Keys.ElementAt(i);
        dict[key]-=1;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary is indexed by a key of type `string` here. So you can do something like this:

```
myDictionary["some value"] -= 1;
```

If you wanted to subtract 1 from every value then you could do it like this:

```
foreach (var key in myDictionary.Keys) 
{
    myDictionary[key] -= 1;
}
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L9CV0B

Comment: @Jamiec Good spot, thanks!

Comment: So the actual problem in OP's code is the fact that `KeyValuePair<string,int>` is a struct, so their code only changed the value in that iterated struct, but not in the dictionary.

Comment: The actual problem is `Value` in `KeyValuePair<K,V>` is readonly!

Comment: I get "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'" so maybe```myDictionary.keys``` in the foreach is not the best solution

Comment: @Las Sincas, if you click on the dotnet fiddle linked in this answer, you see it works...You may want to revise the code above your statements to make it functional

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU that is the code that I have used, and it is where I get the error from